# How to get data from another table through pivot table in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I want to display all food_item_category name in view which is belongs to food item

Here is  my 3table informations

food item table column:  "food_item_id",   "name"  , "image"

food item category table column: "food_item_category_id" ,  "name"

pivot table name "food_items_have_categories" and its column is

-> id,

--> food_item_id

-->food_item_category_id

Here is fooditem model

public function foodItemCategory() {

```
    return $this->belongsToMany(FoodItemCategory::class, 'food_items_have_categories', 'food_item_id', 'food_item_category_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I am displaying food details in ajax request.  Here is my controller

public function getProduct()

{

```
    $products = FoodItem::all();
    return response()->json($products);
}
```

Here is  in view

```
          $.each(response, function(key, value){              
            data = data + "<tr>"
            data = data + "<td>"+i+++"</td>"
            data = data + "<td>"+ "<img src='/storage/items/food/"+value.image+"'/>"  +"</td>"
            data = data + "<td>"+value.name+"</td>"
```

Now, I want to display food_item category in the table. How to do that through pivot table?

Comment: Have you tried? Take a look at "with()" in the relationship docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I tried this way FoodItem::with('foodItemCategory')->get() and get response form that. But when i tried to get data by value.foodItemCategory.name, I didn't get any data. Can you tell me the right way how to show this in view?

Comment: Since it is a many-to-many relationship, the categories will be an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

```
public function foodItemCategory() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(FoodItemCategory::class, 'food_items_have_categories', 'food_item_id', 'food_item_category_id')
        ->withPivot('food_item_id', 'food_item_category_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```